# Is there any nodejs implementation for MAC ANSI X9.19

Tags: node.js, des

I saw the c# implementation for MAC ANSI X9.19 standard in https://blog.canalda.net/Post.aspx?IdPost=478, but I didn't find any solution for nodejs, could anyone help me for this?